# How to override a not plugable parent theme function from a non function.php file?

Tags: php, wordpress, overriding

I want to reduce the number of image files that my parent theme produces. After a little research I found that for this I need to override a function from a php file (**not function.php**) of the parent theme, but this is impossible because **this function is not pluggable** (not wrapped in a *if (!function_exists())* condition). For now, I just wrapped the parent function in a *if (!function_exists())* condition and overridden it in my child theme function.php file.

In the described situation, is possible to override the parent function not changing the parent theme? I ask here because I do not have any reaction from the developer.

I tried to remove the parent theme function with the next code in my child theme and in a plugin, but this didn't helped:

```
function remove_fastnews_actions() {
    remove_action('after_setup_theme','kopa_front_after_setup_theme');
}
add_action('after_setup_theme','remove_fastnews_actions');
//add_action('wp_loaded','remove_fastnews_actions');
```

This is the function I need to override (it is bigger, so I keeped here only what I really need to change):

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'kopa_front_after_setup_theme');

function kopa_front_after_setup_theme() {
    $sizes = array(
        'flexslider-image-size'   => array(500, 500, TRUE, __('Flexslider Post Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
        'article-list-image-size' => array(300, 277, TRUE, __('Article List Post Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
        'article-list-sm-image-size' => array(120, 120, TRUE, __('Article List Small Post Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
        'article-carousel-image-size' => array(354, 354, TRUE, __('Article Carousel Post Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
        'entry-list-image-size' => array(227, 182, TRUE, __('Entry List Thumbnail Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
        'blog-image-size' => array(680, 419, TRUE, __('Blog Image Size (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
    );

    apply_filters('kopa_get_image_sizes', $sizes);

    foreach ($sizes as $slug => $details) {
        add_image_size($slug, $details[0], $details[1], $details[2]);
    }
}
```

The same parent function made pluggable:

```
if( !function_exists('kopa_front_after_setup_theme') )
{

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'kopa_front_after_setup_theme');

function kopa_front_after_setup_theme() {
    $sizes = array(
        'flexslider-image-size'   => array(500, 500, TRUE, __('Flexslider Post Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
        'article-list-image-size' => array(300, 277, TRUE, __('Article List Post Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
        'article-list-sm-image-size' => array(120, 120, TRUE, __('Article List Small Post Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
        'article-carousel-image-size' => array(354, 354, TRUE, __('Article Carousel Post Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
        'entry-list-image-size' => array(227, 182, TRUE, __('Entry List Thumbnail Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
        'blog-image-size' => array(680, 419, TRUE, __('Blog Image Size (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
    );

    apply_filters('kopa_get_image_sizes', $sizes);

    foreach ($sizes as $slug => $details) {
        add_image_size($slug, $details[0], $details[1], $details[2]);
    }
}

}
```

And the child theme function that override the parent function:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'kopa_front_after_setup_theme');

function kopa_front_after_setup_theme() {
    $sizes = array(
        'flexslider-image-size'   => array(0, 0, TRUE, __('Flexslider Post Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
        'article-list-image-size' => array(0, 0, TRUE, __('Article List Post Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
        'article-list-sm-image-size' => array(120, 120, TRUE, __('Article List Small Post Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
        'article-carousel-image-size' => array(0, 0, TRUE, __('Article Carousel Post Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
        'entry-list-image-size' => array(0, 0, TRUE, __('Entry List Thumbnail Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
        'blog-image-size' => array(0, 0, TRUE, __('Blog Image Size (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
    );

    apply_filters('kopa_get_image_sizes', $sizes);

    foreach ($sizes as $slug => $details) {
        add_image_size($slug, $details[0], $details[1], $details[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you could put it in a plugin file.

Comment: Rather than stopping it running, could you call [remove_image_size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_image_size) to remove the unwanted sizes?

Comment: @GopalSRathore - Do you mean the remove_action and the child theme function? I tried this, not working.

Comment: @Hobo - Maybe I can, but I don't understand how to do this in my context :(.

Comment: Sorry, misread your requirement.  Looks like you should be able to use the filter (which I missed before) - see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the original function has a filter in the function, why not take advantage of that?  In your `functions.php`, something like (untested code):

```
add_filter('kopa_get_image_sizes', 'override_kopa_images');

function override_kopa_images($sizes) {
    $new_sizes = array(
        'flexslider-image-size'   => array(0, 0, TRUE, __('Flexslider Post Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
        'article-list-image-size' => array(0, 0, TRUE, __('Article List Post Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
        'article-list-sm-image-size' => array(120, 120, TRUE, __('Article List Small Post Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
        'article-carousel-image-size' => array(0, 0, TRUE, __('Article Carousel Post Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
        'entry-list-image-size' => array(0, 0, TRUE, __('Entry List Thumbnail Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
        'blog-image-size' => array(0, 0, TRUE, __('Blog Image Size (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain())),
    );
    return $new_sizes;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the input variable `$sizes` to change individual entries, eg

```
add_filter('kopa_get_image_sizes', 'override_kopa_images');

function override_kopa_images($sizes) {
    $sizes['flexslider-image-size'] = array(0, 0, TRUE, __('Flexslider Post Image (Kopatheme)', kopa_get_domain()));
    return $sizes;
}
```

Comment: Hobo - this doesn't work. I also tried the @gopal-s-rathore suggestion, but no success. I think this happens because the parent function is not pluggable and because it is in another file, not in function.php.

Comment: Hmm; I'm confused.  The parent function (pluggable or not, defined in functions.php or not) is calling `apply_filters('kopa_get_image_sizes', $sizes);`, so if you've added a filter correctly, it should be called.  Exactly how did you add the filter?

Comment: I added (with copy/paste, checked against errors) your last function to my child theme function.php, then uploaded an image to my site and the image defined as flexslider-image-size was there (I deleted it before this).

Comment: Ah.  Whoever wrote the code used the construct incorrectly.  It should be `$sizes = apply_filters('kopa_get_image_sizes', $sizes);` - they're missing the assignment.  I'm not sure it'll work, but you could try using the second approach and changing the function declaration to use call by reference: `function override_kopa_images(&$sizes) {` (note the `&`).  Does that work?  If not, the filter call as written's pretty useless, I think.

Comment: I replaced the *apply_filters('kopa_get_image_sizes', $sizes);* from the parent theme with the *$sizes = apply_filters('kopa_get_image_sizes', $sizes);* and your second approach worked like a charm! I think the first approach must work too. I will try to contact the developer, but he did not respond to my messages. Or I will fork his theme, but I do not want this. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: Shame it can't be fixed without changing the parent theme (easily, at least - there might still be an approach with `remove_image_size()`).  Anyway, glad to help.

Comment: The _remove_image_size()_ approach not worked because of the same incorrect code, I tried it before. Now it works too.